# get the values of javascript variables from my .aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

SO my task is simple - I've I have a javascript code (actually a code that works with google analytics; anaway that's not important)

```
<script>

     ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
                'id': '52',                 

                'revenue': '599.200',               

            });
          </script>
```

the problem is that these values of id and 'revenue ' I should get it from the server - in this case my aspx page.

so in my aspx.cs I've got one so simple method which returns an object which has id and revenue property; SO the task is I shoudld somehow connect my javascript variables with these properties

```
 protected OrderIndo RenderScript()
  {
    //if (this.OrderID == null) return;

    OrderIndo orderInfo = new OrderInfo();
    orderInfo.id = 12;
    orderInfo.revenue = somestringvariable; 

    return orderInfo;


  }
```

Comment: You need to have a good understanding of the separation between client and server. The server executes, then sends the resulting HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to the client. Then the client runs. And if a postback occurs, the form is posted back to the server, which rerenders itself and sends the new HTML, CSS, and JS to to the client. Therefore,  one of the easiest things to do in this situation is to embed the data in an `<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" id="MyData" />`

Comment: What is `OrderIndo` or `OrderInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `protected` variable of `OrderIndo`at the beginning of your class in codebehind. Fill it in on PageLoad. Render it on your aspx page using

```
<script>

     ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
                'id': '<%=OrderIndo.id%>',                 

                'revenue': '<%=OrderIndo.revenue%>',               

            });
 </script>
```

Comment: if this javascript is in a separate js file, it will not work with server tag <%

Comment: @RicardoPontual yeah but the OP said he had a aspx and aspx.cs page,

Answer (score 0):

As you used the asp.net tag, I assumed you're using Asp.Net Web Forms.

You can simply register the javascript in your code behind, like this:

```
    string gaScript = "<script>ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', { 'id': '{0}', 'revenue': '{1}',  });</script>";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ga", string.Format(gaScript, orderInfo.id, orderInfo.revenue));
```

Or register the variables in code behind:

```
string gaScript = "<script>var gaId='{0}'; var gaRevenue='{1}'</script>";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ga", string.Format(gaScript, orderInfo.id, orderInfo.revenue));
```

And read the variables in javascript:

```
<script>

     ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
                'id': gaId,                 

                'revenue': gaRevenue,               

            });
          </script>
```

Hope it helps